C++ How to define the spaceship operator for a template class?
Im trying to define the spaceship operator for a simple template string class.
namespace mylib
{
    template <size_t N>
    struct String
    {
        String()
        {
            *data = '\0';
        }
    
        String(const char *str)
        {
            size_t l = strlen(str);
    
            if (l >= N)
                throw std::runtime_error(str);
    
            memcpy(data, str, l + 1);
        }
    
        auto operator<=>(const String& str) const
        {
            return data <=> str.data;
        }
    
        char data[N];
    };
}
    
    void test_string()
    {
        mylib::String<16> str1;
        mylib::String<16> str2("Hallo");
        mylib::String<16> str3 = "Hallo";
        mylib::String<16> str4 = "hallo";
        assert(str2 == str3);
        assert(str4 != str2);
        assert(str2 < str4);
        assert(str2 <= str4);
        assert(str4 > str2);
        assert(str4 >= str2);
    
        mylib::String<3> str5 = "Hallo";
    }

But i get some errors.
1>E:\Projects\Windows\ind\IndDlg.cpp(104,2): error C2678: binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'mylib::String<16>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>        'bool operator ==(const D2D1_SIZE_U &,const D2D1_SIZE_U &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'mylib::String<16>' to 'const D2D1_SIZE_U &'

How to define the spaceship operator for a template class?
It should be able to compare strings of different size:
String<16> < String<32>
for example.
I'm using Visual Studio 2022 C++ 20.
Thank you for all the comments!
Here is the new code including all includes and
the template comparison operator.
// String.cpp

#include <cassert>
#include <compare>
#include <stdexcept>

namespace mylib
{

    template <size_t N>
    struct String
    {
        String()
        {
            *data = '\0';
        }

        String(const char* str)
        {
            size_t l = strlen(str);

            if (l >= N)
                throw std::runtime_error(str);

            memcpy(data, str, l + 1);
        }

        template<size_t N2>
        auto operator<=>(const String<N2>& str)
        {
            return strcmp(data, str.data);
        }

        template<size_t N2>
        bool operator==(const String<N2>& str) const
        {
            return operator<=>(str) == 0;
        }

        char data[N];
    };

} // namespace mylib

int main()
{
    mylib::String<16> str1;
    mylib::String<16> str2("Hallo");
    mylib::String<162> str3 = "Hallo";
    mylib::String<16> str4 = "hallo";
    assert(str2 == str3);
    assert(str4 != str2);
    assert(str2 < str4);
    assert(str2 <= str4);
    assert(str4 > str2);
    assert(str4 >= str2);

    mylib::String<3> str5 = "Hallo";

    return 0;
}

Now im getting the following error 4 times:
1>E:\Projects\WindowsTest\String\String.cpp(53,2): error C2666: 'mylib::String<16>::operator <=>': overloaded functions have similar conversions
1>    E:\Projects\WindowsTest\String\String.cpp(29,8):
1>    could be 'auto mylib::String<16>::operator <=><16>(const mylib::String<16> &)' [rewritten expression '0 < (x <=> y)']
1>    E:\Projects\WindowsTest\String\String.cpp(29,8):
1>    or 'auto mylib::String<16>::operator <=><16>(const mylib::String<16> &)' [synthesized expression '(y <=> x) < 0']
1>    E:\Projects\WindowsTest\String\String.cpp(53,2):
1>    while trying to match the argument list '(mylib::String<16>, mylib::String<16>)'

What i am doing wrong?
Now i changed the data from char to array but still get the same  errors as before.
// String.cpp

#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <compare>
#include <stdexcept>

namespace mylib
{

    // This class is for short constant strings on the stack without any overhead.
    template <size_t N>
    struct String
    {
        String()
        {
            *data = '\0';
        }

        String(const char* str)
        {
            size_t l = strlen(str);

            if (l >= N)
                throw std::runtime_error(str);

            memcpy(data, str, l + 1);
        }

        template<size_t N2>
        auto operator<=>(const String<N2>& str)
        {
            return data <=> str.data;
        }

        template<size_t N2>
        bool operator==(const String<N2>& str) const
        {
            return (data <=> str.data) == 0;
        }

        std::array<char, N> data;
    };

} // namespace mylib

int main()
{
    mylib::String<16> str1;
    mylib::String<16> str2("Hallo");
    mylib::String<32> str3 = "Hallo";
    mylib::String<32> str4 = "hallo";
    assert(str2 == str3);
    assert(str4 != str2);
    assert(str2 < str4);
    assert(str2 <= str4);
    assert(str4 > str2);
    assert(str4 >= str2);

    mylib::String<3> str5 = "Hallo";

    return 0;
}


Please don't omit #include, it makes hard to replicate the error in a compiler.

What is D2D1_SIZE_U? Please post a [mre].

The error you posted is not from the code you posted (I don't see any D2D1_SIZE_U in the code). Please post the exact error you get from the posted code (and make it a [mre]).

The errors are worse to read completely. After many fixes in your code I have ended up at error C7611: operator '<=>': not allowed for array types.

What i am doing wrong? Reposting answer in question and asking next question for starters.That's not how it works. You have const-qualified and non-const-qualified version of operator now for some unknown reason, which cannot be selected between, that's clearly stated in the error. comparison operatos aren't access operators. Also strcmp doesn't return value  correct for <=> return type, it just returns an int, doesn't it?

If you want a clarification for an answer it's better to comment on that answer (note that the answer you've chosen contains mistakes which is why you're getting errors)

@AlanBirtles I don't think OP selected any of answers and made up their own. E.g. mine had nothing like that overload error. And strcmp in starship? This moves from "how to define operator" to "how to compare strings". at point one starts to create templates that should be a non-question, becuase tempaltes require esoteric knowledge of syntax rules.

Please don't edit your question to include solutions, questions are for questions, not answers

Please do not edit the quesiton to incorporate answers that were given. Best would be to not edit the question anymore once you received answers. If you have follow up questions you can open a new question. As it currently stands the question and answers are incomprehensible because the answers refer to code that is not the most recent in your question.

char data[N] has no comparison operator defined, if you use std::array<char, N> instead your code will work as it does have a comparison operator.
As a bonus as std::array is your only member you can just use a default operator:
#include <array>

namespace mylib
{
    template <size_t N>
    struct String
    {
        String()
        {
            data.fill('\0');
        }
    
        String(const char *str)
        {
            size_t l = strlen(str);
    
            if (l >= N)
                throw std::runtime_error(str);
    
            memcpy(data.data(), str, l + 1);
        }
    
        auto operator<=>(const String& str) const = default;
    
        std::array<char, N> data;
    };
}

Note that though there's no comparison operator defined for c-style arrays the default comparison operator is defined for array members so if using the default comparison operator you don't have to change to std::array (though I'd still recommend using std::array as it has other benefits over c-style arrays).

You can't compare arrays, that's completely wrong. Replace return data <=> str.data; with actual comparison algorithm. You may actually need separate != operation as a short-circuit.
Each instance of String<N> with unique N value is a unique type, so you have to have a template of operator:
    template <size_t S>
    auto operator<=>(const String<S>& str) const
    {
        //
    }

Another thing would be to have an ability to compare wita  C-string. Which can't be done by this operator, because a pointer C-string doesn't carry size which could be used to construct String:
    auto operator<=>(const char* cstr) const
    {
        //
    }

And we may compare with array (or construct String from array):
    template <size_t S>
    auto operator<=>(const char (&array)[S]) const
    {
        //
    }

PS. You likely would need also a a constructor like that.Your string is also able to fail if source isn't null-terminated, strlen will have ndefined behaviour.

"You can't compare arrays, that's completely wrong" why not ? std::array has operator== https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/operator_cmp

oh sorry, the question has been modified to show very different code. Imho it should be rolled back because its confusing and a pity for the effort that has been put into answers, I am just too late to know what was the state of the question when the answers have been written

@463035818_is_not_an_ai all the answers were written based on the first code block which is still in the question

@AlanBirtles yes, I would roll it back, but I dont want to make it worse ;)

@463035818_is_not_an_ai and these technically aren't arrays. Yeah, for me std::array in a pinch would be go-to too, but I rather would use or build a proper implementation of static string , with constexpr support.

When you overload the spaceship operator (<=>), it automatically provides default behavior for other relational operators (<, <=, >, >=) but not for operators (== and !=) by providing overloading for ==(it will also cover !=).
Also, spaceship operator does not work directly with arrays, it works with objects that have a defined spaceship operator.
This is updated code
#include <iostream>
#include <compare>
#include <string.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <string_view>

namespace mylib
{
    template <size_t N>
    struct String
    {
        String()
        {
            *data = '\0';
        }
    
        String(const char *str)
        {
            size_t l = strlen(str);
    
            if (l >= N)
                throw std::runtime_error(str);
    
            memcpy(data, str, l + 1);
        }
    
        auto operator<=>(const String& str) const
        {
            auto result = std::string_view(data) <=> std::string_view(str.data);;
            return result;
        }
        
        bool operator==(const String& str) const {
            return data == str.data;
        }
    
        char data[N];
    };
}

int main()
{
     mylib::String<16> str1;
        mylib::String<16> str2("Hallo");
        mylib::String<16> str3 = "Hallo";
        mylib::String<16> str4 = "hallo";
        assert(str2 == str3);
        assert(str4 != str2);
        assert(str2 < str4);
        assert(str2 <= str4);
        assert(str4 > str2);
        assert(str4 >= str2);
    
        mylib::String<3> str5 = "Hallo";

    return 0;
}


You don't need an explicit operator== when you have a three way comparison operator https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons. data == str.data doesn't work either

"... it automatically provides default behavior for other relational operators (<, <=, >, >=) but not for operators (== and !=) by providing overloading for ==(it will also cover !=)." the sentence seem to miss a word (or more). "it provides default behavior for other relational operators but not for operators" makes no sense

Implementing non-equality makes sense. There use to be version of compiler which didn't support that
